# Generalisations in Use Case Diagrams

Tags: use-case

The application I'm creating allows the sales team, and development team to manipulate 'environments'. I am visualising this through a use-case diagram.

Essentially, both roles are able to search/display environments, view their details, before performing certain actions. In the following diagram, this is clearly shown from the Sales Team entity.

The development team, is able to do ALL the functions of the sales team + more advanced functions (e.g. clone, deactivate, backup, as shown in the diagram) - hence why there is a generalisation. These functions, however, should extend from 'View Environment Information'. I'm not sure how to represent this without creating three duplicated use cases which already exist in the Sales team...

Would duplicating that section be the only option to show functions specific to each role?

[image: Use Case Diagram]

Comment: "These functions, however, should extend from 'View Environment Information'" - Why? (I mean, elaborate how you conceptualized this - why are these extensions of this particular use case.)

Comment: Hey Filip, imagine you have a shopping app where you browse for items. You click on an item to view its details, and from there, you can purchase it, add it to your wishlist, share it + other functions. This is like my situation, where cloning, deactivating etc are actions that only development team can access, but stem from the viewing environment info page.

Comment: But that's my point - use cases don't map directly to pages/screens; they represent the conceptual usage cases or usage scenarios of the system. You can treat "View/search Environment Info" as an independent use case from "Edit Environment Details", or "Clone Environment", or "Backup Environment" (If that way of thinking makes sense for the problem domain you are dealing with; you can conceptualize your system in different ways). My point is: the fact that you get there from the view env. info screen doesn't necessarily mean that these use cases should extend "View Environment Information".